# Cast type which i don't know yet what is it

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

let's say i have list with properties like this:

```
Type ArrayType
String Value
```

i've got another list like this:

```
ArrayType=System.Int32
Value=44
Index=0

ArrayType=System.Int32
Value=11
Index=3

ArrayType=System.Int32
Value=7
Index=2

ArrayType=System.Int32
Value=5
Index=1
```

All values are in string !
I don't know what type will be it, int32 is only example. there will also be floats, strings, etc.

so... i'm creating new array of type which i readed from "ArrayType" property

```
dynamic newArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeOfArray, arraySize);
```

*I know arraySize of coure*

and the Arrays are created properly.
But now i want to copy all values (which are in string) to my new array:
but i have no idea how to cast it. i've tried something like this:

```
newArray.SetValue(element.Property.Value,element.Index);
```

it throw an exception that he can't write OBJECT to my array of ints

so then i've tried to cast in somehow:

```
 newArray[element.Index] = Convert.ChangeType(element.Property.Value,element.Property.Type);
```

but it still can't cast the object

can someone help :) ?

Comment: Use reflection to set the array values.

Comment: This sounds like it might be [an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why do you need to do this?

Comment: lets say i will get values with types from database and i have create dynamicly objects from these values

Comment: So you have an array of unknown type, and you want to turn it into an array of strings? Is that right?

Comment: Are all values in the array going to be converted to the same type or do you mix float and int for example in the same array?

Comment: there will be a lot of different types. there are simple types like int, float, strings, but also there will be a types that someone will create and pack them into container. There will be also array of simple types, and array of classess which i don't know yet. My code now gets values from the container and from here it can create objects (it takes property names and types and then creating object of this non-known-yet class)

Comment: How do you expect to mix different types in the same array?

Comment: i wont't. let's say there will be in database records like this:
someFloat[0] ; 12.5
someFloat[2] ; 24.5
someFloat[1] ; 31.5
someInteger[0] ; 31
someInteger[2]; 32
someInteger[1]; 44

and now i will create array by getting type of someInteger
and then i have to create table of integers and table of float

Comment: Why do you repeat array type for each item? That normally should be a property of *array* (not *array item*). Another problem is what you have to read all items before you know array size. Who designed such database and why? Do you really need those fields (e.g. to run query over array items directly using database and never loading complete array into memory)? Or you simply want to save *small* array into database? Then it's basically 3 fields: array type, version and then serialized array data (as json or binary).

Comment: i dont repeat array type for each item. i have just created some class property and i use object of "property" in my class ArrayOfProperties, which has ArrayIndex(int) and Property(property)   i know size before creating table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made this code example:

```
var types = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(float), typeof(double) };
var elements = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
                       .Select((value, index) => new Element(types[index % types.Length], value.ToString(), index));

var integers = elements.Where(element => element.ArrayType == typeof(int));
var array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 100);

Console.WriteLine(array.GetType());

foreach(var element in integers)
{
    var value = Convert.ChangeType(element.Value, element.ArrayType);
    array.SetValue(value, element.Index);
}

foreach(var value in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value + " " + value.GetType());
}
```

Element class:

```
public class Element
{
    public Type ArrayType { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    public int Index { get; private set; }

    public Element(Type type, string value, int index)
    {
        ArrayType = type;
        Value = value;
        Index = index;
    }
}
```

[Which just works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hG2UJh)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now all works :D thanks for help!

```
   foreach (var element in groupedElement)
                {
                    var newInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(element.Property.Type);

                    newInstance = element.Property.Value;

                    newArray.SetValue(Convert.ChangeType(newInstance, element.Property.Type, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), element.Index);
                }
```